# Что означает const*?

Tags: c++, c, указатели, объявление

Именно со звездой - демонические конструкции могут принимать вид

`const char* const* blah_blah`,

`char const* blah`

`int const* const integer`,

`int* const* const` и так далее в самых разных комбинациях. Как расшифровать сии начертания и зачем вообще может кому-то понадобиться оборачиваться в `const`, будто шелкопряду?

Comment: [cdecl](http://cdecl.org/?q=const+char*+const*+blah_blah)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Такие записи проще всего рассматривать справа налево. Например,

Данное объявление

```
const char * const  * blah_blah;
```

объявляет указатель с именем `blah_blah`, который указывает на константный указатель (так как квалификатор const предшествует *, если смотреть справа налево), который указывает на константный объект типа `char`.

Вот пример простой программы, который облегчает понимание этого объявления.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    const char * const  * blah_blah;
    const char *p = "Hello";
    blah_blah = &p;
    puts( *blah_blah );
}
```

На консоль будет выведено

```
Hello
```

Можно ввести `typedef` имена для наглядности

```
typedef const char CONST_CHAR_TYPE;
typedef CONST_CHAR_TYPE *POINTER_TO_CONST_CHAR_TYPE;

const POINTER_TO_CONST_CHAR_TYPE *blah_blah;
```

в этом случае переменная `blah_blah` является указателем на константный указатель на константный объект типа `char`.

Я думаю будет легче понять эти объявления, если следовать грамматике определения указателя.

Указатель в стандарте C определяется следующим образом

```
pointer: 
    * type-qualiﬁer-listopt 
    * type-qualiﬁer-listopt pointer
```

то есть за знаком * может следовать список квалификации, который к нему относится.

Поэтому предыдущее объявление можно записать как

```
const char ( * const ( *blah_blah ) );
```

Можно сделать и сам указатель `blah_blah` константным. Но тогда он должен быть явно инициализирован при объявлении, если имеет автоматическую продолжительность памяти. Например

```
const char ( * const ( * const blah_blah ) ) = /* некоторое значение */;
```

или

```
const char * const * const blah_blah  = /* некоторое значение */;
```

Вот демонстрационная программа, в которой сам указатель `blah_blah` также объявлен как константный.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    const char *p = "Hello";
    const char ( * const ( * const  blah_blah ) ) = &p;
    puts( *blah_blah );
}
```

Объявление этого указателя читается как *константный указатель на константный указатель на константный объект типа char*.

В объявления функций, имеющих прототип, можно опускать идентификатор параметра.

Ниже представлена такая программа

```
#include <stdio.h>

void display( const char ( * const ( * const ) ) );
void display( const char * const * const );
void display( const char ( * const  ( * ) ) );
void display( const char * const  * );

int main(void) 
{
    const char *p = "Hello";
    display( &p );
}

void display( const char * const * const blah_blah )
{
    puts( *blah_blah );
}
```

Так как объявлений одной и той же функции (без ее определения) может быть несколько, то все выше указанные функции объявляют одну и ту же функцию. Так называемый квалификатор верхнего уровня, который относится непосредственно к параметру, можно убрать из объявления функции. То есть (еще один пример) эти пары функций объявляют одни и те же функции

```
void f( const int x );
void f( int x );
```

и

```
void g( int * const p );
void g( int * p );
```

Answer (score 11):

В языках С и С++ нередко используется [неформальная/полуформальная] концепция *пути доступа* (access path) к объекту. А именно: указатель (или ссылка) на объект является *путем доступа* к этому объекту. Пути доступа бывают *константные* и *неконстантные*. Через константные пути доступа объект модифицировать нельзя, через неконстантные - можно (при условии, что сам объект является модифицируемым). К одному и тому же объекту могу вести как константные так и неконстантные пути доступа.

```
int a = 42;
int *pa = &a;
const int *ca = &a;
// `*pa` - неконстантный путь доступа к `a`
// `*ca` - константный путь доступа к `a`
```

Приведенные вами примеры использования модификатора `const` на более глубоких уровнях вложенности в объявлениях указателей (т.е. слева от `*`) как раз управляют *константностью пути доступа*, то есть разрешают или запрещают модификацию указуемого объекта *через данный путь доступа*.

(Из ряда вот выходит только ваш последний пример, где крайний правый `const` задает константность самого указателя `integer`, а не пути доступа к указуемому объекту.)

Если один и то же объект виден вам как через константный, так и через неконстантный путь доступа, то модификация этого объекта, сделанная через неконстантный путь доступа, будет тут же видна через константный путь доступа

```
int a = 42;
int *pa = &a;
const int *ca = &a;

*pa = 5;
// Теперь значение `*ca` равно 5
```

То есть ваши модификаторы `const` не говорят о том, что указуемый объект не может изменяться. Они лишь не дают вам модифицировать указуемый объект *именно через этот путь доступа*. Таким образом управление константностью пути доступа является в основном средством самодисциплины. Однако в коде, с самого начала грамотно и активно использующем константность объектов, обойтись без использования этого средства невозможно.

Правила константной корректности языка С и С++ позволяют вам свободно превращать неконстантные пути доступа в константные

```
int a = 42;
int *pa = &a;
// `*pa` - неконстантный путь доступа к `a`
const int *ca = pa;
// `*ca` - константный путь доступа к `a`
```

но обратное превращение невозможно. (Путем использования `const_cast` или C-style cast можно "грубой силой" превращать константные пути доступа в неконстантные, но это уже другая история.)

Можно дополнительно заметить, что правила константной корректности языков С и С++ несколько отличаются, что приводит к ряду сохраняющихся по сей день "нелогичностей" в языке С, давно устраненных в языке С++

```
int **p = 0;
const int *const *ccp = p; // Ошибка в С, разрешено в С++

int a[10] = { 0 };
const int (*сpa)[10] = &a; // Ошибка в С, разрешено в С++
```

Это временами мешает полноценно пользоваться константными путями доступа в С.

Comment: скажите, пожалуйста, в каком месте `Стандарта C++` написано о том, что указатель или ссылка на константу позволяют увидеть изменение первоначального изменяемого объекта? Я очень хочу найти эту информацию.

Answer (score 7):

Ну смотрите, например:

```
int j;    //  Переменная типа int, в нее можно писать, что угодно.
int * pi; //  Указатель на переменную int, в которую можно писать: *pi = 5;
const int * cpi; // Указатель на константную переменную int,
                 // которую можно только читать: о = *cpi;
                 // Сам указатель можно менять: cpi = &j;
const int * const ccpi; // Константный указатель на константную переменную.
                        // И переменную, на которую он указывает, можно только читать, 
                        // и сам указатель нельзя изменять...
```

Так более-менее понятно?

Более сложные варианты могут включать, например, константный указатель на вот такой константный указатель, как `ccpi` выше :)

Comment: Константный указатель на константную переменную означает, что вот эту конкретную переменную нельзя менять ну никак-никак ни при каких условиях (какая важная переменная)?

Comment: Что нельзя менять ни указатель (он константный), ни то, на что он указывает (на константную переменную). Обойти, конечно, можно - путем приведения к неконстантному, но зачем?... В принципе умный компилятор может, основываясь на таком обещании константности, существенно оптимизировать код.

Comment: @Harry: Чтобы оптимизировать код на основе обещаний константности *указуемых объектов* компилятор должен иметь полное представление об aliasing в рассматриваемом участке кода. Без исчерпывающего понимания aliasing picture компилятор не сможет воспользоваться этими `const` для оптимизации (ибо даже несмотря на наличие `const` указуемый объект может меняться). А при наличии полного понимания aliasing picture компилятор сумеет точно так же соптимизировать код даже и без `const`. По этой причине константность *указуемых объектов*, к сожалению, обычно никак не может улучшить оптимизацию кода.

Comment: Оптимизацию в таких ситуациях улучшают `restrict` и правило strict-aliasing. И если они "срабатывают", то полезный оптимизационный эффект от этого никак не зависит  от наличия или отсутствия `const`. По этой причине можно утверждать, что константность указуемых объектов - это не более чем средство самодисциплины.

Comment: @AnT Да-да, особенно часто `restrict` используется в C++...

Comment: @Harry: Вопрос помечен [C] и [C++].